# How do I fix package dependencies when using a different cudatoolkit than my nvidia cluster is using?

Tags: tensorflow, dependencies, gpu, nvidia, tensorrt

I am using a package that requires tensorflow-gpu == 2.0.0 and CUDA=10.0.0 with cudann==7.6.0

I am running this code on a NVIDIA gpu cluster and when I run nvidia-smi it shows
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLCRT.png). It still shows cuda 11, which I guess is the one installed on the actually server.

I was told that I can basically 'override' this version by installing the cudatoolkit in the version that I need. I did that and installed cudatoolkit==10.0.

Unfortunately I am now running into a problem when trying to run an LSTM based model with tensorflow-gpu. I get the following:

```bash
2022-06-14 17:02:26.988359: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-11.2/lib64
2022-06-14 17:02:26.989175: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-11.2/lib64
2022-06-14 17:02:26.989208: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:30] Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
```

In the path I still see cuda11. Is this causing the problem? How can I resolve this?

Comment: a proper CUDA install (let's say for the 10.x version you want) includes having PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH variables set correctly, to reflect the CUDA version you are trying to use.  If you are trying to use CUDA 10.x its evident you have not done that.  The error output is telling your that your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable is set incorrectly.  This topic is covered in numerous questions here on SO, as well as the NVIDIA CUDA linux install guide, and probably other places as well.  Also, importantly, the actual problem here seems to be that it can't find libnvinfer, which is part of TensorRT.

Comment: I have now updated the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. As you said, the problem solves the problem for tensorflow 2.0. However, it turned out I needed 2.1 (for a different reason) to get the LSTM to work and now I have the same problem, even when I set the ld path. It seems that it looks for TensorRT 6, while tf gpu looks for TensorRT 5. Since it is on a gpu server of the university, I dont have sudo rights to install TensorRT 6. Is there a work around for this?

Comment: If your tf needs ("looks for") TRT5, then you need to make sure that TRT5 is in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  Just repeat that entire statement for TRT6.  ("If your tf needs TRT6, ...").  You don't need sudo rights to install TRT6 (or 5) in a location in your user directory space) and you can easily have your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` point to whereever that may be.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the comment you need to use `TensorFlow 2.1`, then you need to install `cuDNN 7.6` and `CUDA 10.1` specifically.

Please follow the below [tested build configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu) to know about `Python` and `TensorFlow` versions compatible `CUDA` and `cuDNN` .
[image]

Please check this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) for more details on GPU setup.